# Unmanaged code calling managed code works on dev machine, not on deployed machine

Tags: c#, c++, interop, com-interop, directshow

I am building a webcam app based on the VideoRendererElement project (http://videorendererelement.codeplex.com/), which uses the DirectShowLib and Interop with an unmanaged activex component. I am using Visual Studio 2010, but am targeting .NET 3.5 (2.0 clr runtime).

I have been able to build and run the app on my development machine with no problem (outside of Visual Studio, even). However, when I deployed the app on the target machine (Windows 7,.NET up to date, C++ redistributable up to date) the app crashes. I set up an additional method to log the running application to a text file on the target machine a traced down one key difference, the unmanaged code calls the method in the managed code, only the static fields defined previously are missing. This only happens on the target machine (the one I deployed the code to). Here are some code snippets and what I logged. What is confusing is that this error ONLY occurs on the target machine. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace MediaBridge
{
    .....

    public class MediaBridgeManager
    {
        public delegate void NewMediaGraphInfo(MediaBridgeGraphInfo GraphInfo);

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, NewMediaGraphInfo> _delegateHash = new Dictionary<string, NewMediaGraphInfo>();

        ......

        public static void AddMediaGraphInfo(MediaBridgeGraphInfo GraphInfo)
        {
            if (_delegateHash.ContainsKey(GraphInfo.MediaUrl))
            {
                NewMediaGraphInfo callback = _delegateHash[GraphInfo.MediaUrl];
                _delegateHash.Remove(GraphInfo.MediaUrl);

                /* Suppress all errors on the callback */
                try
                {
                    callback(GraphInfo);
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }

        ......

        public static bool RegisterCallback(string MediaUrl, NewMediaGraphInfo Callback)
        {
            bool returnval = true;
            MediaUrl = FormatUrl(MediaUrl);

            if (!_delegateHash.ContainsKey(MediaUrl))
            {
                _delegateHash.Add(MediaUrl, Callback);
            }
            else
            {
                returnval = false;
            }

            return returnval;
        }
    }
}
```

Before the .NET part of the app calls RegisterCallback() first and populates _delegateHash with a URL and callback function. This was verified in the logfile on the target machine.

Now the unmanaged part:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMediaBridgeSourceFilter::Load(LPCOLESTR lpwszFileName, const AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt)
{
    /* Thread-saftey */
    CAutoLock cAutoLockShared(&m_cSharedState);

    HRESULT phr = S_OK;

    /* Create the output pin for our filter */
    m_pPin = new CMediaBridgeSourceFilterPin(&phr, this);

    /* Create a new class to store information about us/graph in it */
    MediaBridge::MediaBridgeGraphInfo ^ graphInfo = gcnew MediaBridge::MediaBridgeGraphInfo();

    /* Set the media url sent */
    graphInfo->MediaUrl = gcnew System::String(lpwszFileName);

    /* Set the pointer to the filter graph */
    graphInfo->FilterGraph = System::IntPtr(this->GetFilterGraph());

    /* Store the pointer for our instance of the filter */
    graphInfo->SourceFilter = System::IntPtr(this);

    /* Do the callback into our managed code */
    MediaBridge::MediaBridgeManager::AddMediaGraphInfo(graphInfo);

    return phr;
}
```

According to my log file MediaBridge::MediaBridgeManager::AddMediaGraphInfo() is being called on the .NET side but the call back is never reached because the _delegateHash variable is now empty.

Here is what my log file says on the target machine that I'm trying to deploy the app on:

```
RegisterCallback(): MediaUrl = dshowmediabridge://d0ffd222-d023-483b-8fc7-4b4035ce3922/ Contains Key: True Delegate Hash count: 1

InitializeDirectShow(): RegisterCallback == true, Url == DShowMediaBridge://d0ffd222-d023-483b-8fc7-4b4035ce3922

AddMediaGraphInfo(): MediaUrl = dshowmediabridge://d0ffd222-d023-483b-8fc7-4b4035ce3922/ FilterGraph: 71122304 Contains Key: False Delegate Hash count: 0
```

Note how the Delegate Hash count (_delegateHash.Count) is now at 0 when the unmanaged code calls AddMediaGraphInfo().

Is there something I should be doing to identify the dll to COM/C++ on the target machine that VS is doing for me on my development machine?

Comment: Did you compile in debug mode ? you may have a DLL problem with VS debug mode redist dll that are only installed on PC with VS on it. Try in release ...

Comment: Thanks J.N. I had built the solution in release mode.

Comment: While I'm still not 100% sure why it worked on the development box, but since this was an open source solution built from Visual Studio 2005/2008 that I imported into VS 2010 I tried copying the original activex control file into the app's directory overwriting what VS2010 built with the solution, re-registering it and now it works. I'm thinking it had something to do with VS 2010 building it with a later version of the Windows SDK (7.1) or later version of MSBuild targeting .NET 4 which I understand there are fundamental changes with how .NET 4 handles interop with COM.

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying and running the application on the target machine. Are you simply copying over the executable or are you creating an installer? If you are creating an installer, are you registering the AX file with RegSvr32?

The issue with COM components is they have to be registered in the registry on the box in question. On your box, you already have this registered, so you will not have an issue. On the target box, however, it may or may not be registered, at the whim of the user. If you have set up an installer, you have to "install" the AX file so it is registered in the registry. If not, the AX file cannot be found, no matter how you deploy the AX file. It is one of the downsides to COM.

Comment: Thanks Gregory. I had created an installer then copied over and ran regsvr32 manually on the box I deployed it to.